# how to have a variable accessible even when a window is closed

Tags: variables, pysimplegui

Good afternoon,
I'm brand new with PySimpleGUI and I would like to know if it's possible to create a variable from input of button in one window that can be available as a global variable everywhere in the main program even when the window is closed.

Thanks for help

Comment: Just define the variable by `global` statement, and it will always be there even window closed.

Comment: I've already tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Show your code here, maybe this issue not same as in your description.

Answer (score 0):

Temp Code - variables `a` created and still keep the same after window close.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
layout = [
    [sg.T("Window")],
    [sg.Button("Create"), sg.Button("Exit")],
]
window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event == "Create":
        exec("a=10")

window.close()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Finally i've found that my problem was due to the identation of a part of it. Now the global declaration works as it must.